# Como recuperar senha MYSQL com erro no mysqld

Tags: mysql

hoje estava querendo alterar a senha do root do meu mysql que esta em um windows server 2008. Porém eu acabei esquecendo a senha, pesquisando verifiquei varias técnicas parando o mysql e executando o comando mysqld-nt ...

Porem ocorre este erro:

```
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin>
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin>mysqld-nt
'mysqld-nt' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Alguem pode me ajudar?

Comment: Se o `nt` é o argumento, da um espaço depois do `mysqld` se não ele vai tentar achar um executável com esse nome.

Comment: Certo @rray, tentei realizar os comandos, veja:
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin>mysqld -nt
2016-07-06 17:20:20 0 [Warning] option 'new': boolean value 't' wasn't recognize
d. Set to OFF.
2016-07-06 17:20:20 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is depreca
ted. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentati
on for more details).
2016-07-06 17:20:20 0 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 5.6.25) starting as process 5048 ...

Answer (score 2):

Antes de mais nada, o erro apresentado é simplesmente pelo fato de você ou não ter um executável com este nome na máquina, ou de não estar executando com o caminho correto.

Uma vez localizado o executável correto, vamos à questão da senha (no caso do Windows nem precisa, basta fazer tudo pelo painel de Serviços, o `services.msc`).

Existe uma possibilidade que é usar uma opção de inicialização para isso:

```
--skip-grant-tables
```

O cuidado a se tomar é que esta opção faz com que o MySQL aceite como root qualquer usuário que se conecte, portanto, só deve ser usada para que você tenha acesso ao DB e resolva o problema da senha.

Para usar via linha de comando, basta parar a instância e rodar manualmente com o parâmetro `--skip-grant-tables`, arrumar o DB pondo a senha desejada da maneira que achar mais conveniente, e **depois de trocada a senha** reiniciar o serviço normalmente **sem o `--skip-grant-tables`**)

No Windows, pode rodar o `services.msc` e colocar o parâmetro nas opções de inicialização da respectiva instância e reiniciar o serviço (e remover logo em após a troca de senha, reiniciando o serviço normalmente).

**Convém bloquear o acesso de terceiros à maquina durante a manutenção, caso opte por esta solução.**

### Considerações extras:

Se for fazer a alteração localmente, usar este parâmetro é de grande valia:

```
 --bind-address=127.0.0.1
```

Isto faz com que a instância responda só ao endereço local, deixando a operação mais segura.

Se precisar especificar onde esta o `my.ini` ou arquivo equivalente, já que está chamando o servidor manualmente, tem esta opção:

```
--defaults-file=/etc/my.ini
```

### Alternativa com script de inicialização

Originalmente esta era uma resposta do usuário [Bruno Bermann](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/37424), mas que por alguma razão [foi removida](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/139219/revisions). Não testei, mas em teoria faz algum sentido. Fica aqui como referência para quem queira testar.

Em linhas gerais, você pode especificar um arquivo de inicialização assim:

```
mysqld --init-file="C:\\Caminho\\init.txt"
```

e, em teoria, neste caminho poderia ter algo do tipo

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('SenhaNova') WHERE user='root';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

para alterar a senha desejada.

Comment: Olá @bacco estou tentando via linha de comando, faço o seguinte: 1. Paro o serviço chamado MySQL56. 2: executo via linha de comando mysqld-nt --skip-grant-tables. 3 executo o comando mysqld --init-file="C:\\init.txt" e depois encerro o processo mysqld e inicio novaente o MySQL56 mas não modificada a senha :/

Comment: ou usa um ou outro. não faz sentido usar init se vai pular as grants.

Comment: entendi, parei o serviço e dei o comando C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin>mysqld --init-file="C:\\init.txt"
2016-07-06 20:37:30 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is depreca
ted. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentati
on for more details).
2016-07-06 20:37:30 0 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 5.6.25) starting as process 5064 ... Porém ficou travado nisso! :(

Comment: Minha sugestão original é você pular a grant table e trocar a senha como está acostumado, conforme a primeira parte da resposta, e esquecer essa coisa de init. Quanto aos outros erros, é problema na sua configuração do MySQL.

Comment: Precisa ver se não é o caso de fazer backup dos dados, testar o backup pra ver se está ok, e depois reinstalar o serviço, se for um servidor muito desatualizado.

Comment: Boas noticias, deu certo, consegue para o serviço, inserir mysqld --skip-grant-tables e depois acessar o mysql e alterar a senha com o seguinte "UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('SenhaNova') WHERE user='root';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;" apareceu as linhas alteradas e Reiniciei o serviço do MySQL56 mas não consegui logar.

Comment: Precisa ver se o root tá com permissão de logar em qualquer IP, e o ideal pra mudar a senha e host estando com acesso é usando o comando grant tradicional, e não mexendo na tabela user diretamente.

Comment: Fiz tudo correto, consigo logar enquano troco a senha, mas quando inicio o serviço novamente o mysql simplesmente não reconhece minha senha :/ @Bacco

Comment: Você permitiu acesso pelo seu host ao trocar a senha?

Comment: Como assim? Podes me explicar? Troquei assim SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('xxxxxxxx');

Comment: Sugeriria vc ler com mais atenção as recomendações acima, e estudar o comando grant do mysql. Nele vc especifica nome do usuário, privilégios, senha e HOST. Não adianta você saber a senha e o nome do user se o IP/Host que está usando não tem autorização para aquela conta. Se quiser que a conta seja acessada de qualquer máquina, precisa por um % no lugar do host. Aqui tem uns exemplos de como mudar com grant ou com update: http://serverfault.com/questions/483339/changing-host-permissions-for-mysql-users#483364

Comment: Infelizmente desta vez só consegui resolver na época reinstalando totalmente o sql. Mas obrigado pela atenção @Bacco