# Deletei sem querer todos usuários do MySQL phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Eu estava seguindo uns tutoriais na internet para alterar a senha do meu usuário mysql no phpMyAdmin e no final acabei por deletar este usuário. Fiquei sem acesso ao phpMyAdmin e não sei como solucionar este problema, estou usando o Wamp Server.

Aparece a seguinte mensagem:

> #1130 - Host 'localhost' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server

Existe alguma forma de reiniciar ou voltar as definições de origem?

Comment: Vc consegue logar como root?

Comment: Não consigo, perdi todo acesso

Comment: De uma olhada [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1878480/5429980).

Comment: Tem sim, já postei aqui no site. é só iniciar o server com --skip-grant-tables https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/139224/70 e recriar os usuários desejados (ou simplesmente consertar o que estragou). LEIA ATENTAMENTE OS RISCOS E CUIDADOS NA RESPOSTA

Comment: Vide aqui como inicializar o MySQL com acesso incondicional: [Como recuperar senha MYSQL com erro no mysqld](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/139178/70)

Answer (score -1):

Tente o que esta na resposta a esta outra pergunta de um utilizador em uma situação idêntica a referida por si. [AQUI!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14512855/i-accidentally-deleted-the-admin-account-in-my-phpmyadmin-how-can-i-re-give-pri)

A solução apresentada é executar um ficheiro `.bat` na pasta do `xampp` ou se não existir executar o seguinte código:

```
@echo off
echo USE mysql; >resetroot.sql
echo. >>resetroot.sql
echo REPLACE INTO user VALUES ('localhost', 'root', '', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', '', '', '', '', 0, 0, 0, 0, '', ''); >>resetroot.sql
echo REPLACE INTO user VALUES ('127.0.0.1', 'root', '', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', '', '', '', '', 0, 0, 0, 0, '', ''); >>resetroot.sql
echo REPLACE INTO user VALUES ('localhost', 'pma', '', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', '', '', '', '', 0, 0, 0, 0, '', ''); >>resetroot.sql

bin\mysqld.exe --no-defaults --bind-address=127.0.0.1 --bootstrap --console --standalone <resetroot.sql >nul
del resetroot.sql
echo.
echo Passwoerter fuer Benutzer "root" und "pma" wurden geloescht.
echo Passwords for user "root" and "pma" were deleted.
echo.
pause
```

E no `mysql` execute o seguinte:

```
REPLACE INTO user VALUES ('localhost', 'root', '', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', '', '', '', '', 0, 0, 0, 0, '', ''); 
REPLACE INTO user VALUES ('127.0.0.1', 'root', '', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', '', '', '', '', 0, 0, 0, 0, '', ''); 
REPLACE INTO user VALUES ('localhost', 'pma', '', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', '', '', '', '', 0, 0, 0, 0, '', '');
```